# I want to know how to use socket io to make private chat application like WhatsApp one to one chating

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Help me what o have to study  or refer to better understanding  any YouTube channel u can refer me to do better understanding

It's for a learning purpose as i am beginner

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.